# Listen to page save event in a Chrome extension and Firefox addon

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, events, firefox-addon, add-on

I am in the process of developing a plug-in which needs to be notified when a web page is saved. I have been browsing the chrome extension API for a long time now and cannot seem to find a solution to this.

Does such an event exist and is it possible to listen to it?

If not, is this possible with Firefox addons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible with Chrome add-ons. As to Firefox - sure, there is a [`<command>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/command) with ID `Browser:SavePage` in the main browser window (`browser.xul`), defined in [one of the include files](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c722928d8b69/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc#l62). You could add a listener for the `command` event on this element for example:

```
document.getElementById('Browser:SavePage').addEventListener('command', function(e) {
    console.log('doing command', 'id:', e.target.id, 'e:', e);
}, false);
```